# shell script for date checking between two days

Tags: shell, scripting, date

There is date in my file, like 30-apr-2015. How can I compare this  with the current date and get notified if they are equal?

Comment: Have you made an effort to write the script? If you have, please paste the portion of your code and the issue you are facing and we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

This code does the comparison and informs you by printing a message on the console where you typed the command:

```
[[ $(date +%Y%m%d -d $(< file)) == $(date +%Y%m%d) ]] && echo "wake up"
```

You may want to replace the `echo` by any other command that notifies you, e.g., use the command `mail`.